# JAVA- Best way to convert JSON to PDF

Tags: java, json, pdf, spring-rest

I have a RESTFul web-service that sends JSON as an output but now I need to modify that service to return PDF [basically convert that JSON to PDF]
I have read many post which states convert JSON to XML and then to PDF document.

Is there any better way by which my service can directly convert JSON to PDF and send that PDF as response.

Thank you!

Comment: There are many ways to create a pdf. One thing I would recommend that you think about is the differences between json and pdf.

Comment: There are many ways to create a pdf. One thing I would recommend that you think about is the differences between json and pdf. Json is a data format and pdf is a document format. The biggest difference is that json exists for computers to read, and pdfs are for people to read. I would recommend designing a nice layout for your pdf and populating it with data extracted from the json, rather than the pdf displaying a json dump.

Answer (score -1):

Add following Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.56</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Pretify your JSON with Gson:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement je = jp.parse(uglyJSONString);
String prettyJsonString = gson.toJson(je);
```

Create your PDF file using the following script:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("myJSON.pdf"));

document.open();
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 16, BaseColor.BLACK);
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(prettyJsonString, font);

document.add(chunk);
document.close();
```